# Deploying Play 2.1-SNAPSHOT based application to Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I have a Play 2.1-SNAPSHOT based application that runs fine locally but when I try to deploy to Heroku I get the following error:

> ```
>    [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>    [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>    [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>    [warn]   :: play#sbt-plugin;2.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
>    [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>    [warn]
>    [warn]   Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check  that these dependencies exist with the requested
> ```
>
> attributes.

My plugins.sbt file points to a local repository containing the 2.1-SNAPSHOT dependencies:

```
resolvers ++= Seq( 
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  Resolver.file("My Repository", file( "repository/local") )
)

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT")
```

The directory "repository/local" is checked into my GIT repository.  It does look like SBT on Heroku is looking in the local repository since before the "Unresolved Dependency" error I see the following warnings:

> ```
>    [warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
>    [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/2.1-SNAPSHOT/sbt-plugin-2.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
>    [warn] ==== My Repository: tried
>    [warn] ==== heroku-sbt-typesafe: tried
>    [warn] ==== heroku-central: tried
> ```

Running the command "play stage" locally finishes successfully.

Comment: I think another approach is to add the CloudBees CI Snapshot repo instead of using a local file repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue.  I needed to declare "My Repository" as an Ivy repository by adding "Resolver.ivyStylePatterns" after the file resolver like this:

```
Resolver.file("My Repository", file( "repository/local/") )(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is to add the Typesafe [ivy-snapshots](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots/) repository as a plugin resolver if you'd prefer to not use a local file repo.

In *project/plugins.sbt*:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("Typesafe Ivy Snapshots", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots/` seems no longer active, the following configuration works for me:

in your plugins.sbt:

```
//play sbt-plugin snapshot

resolvers += Resolver.url("Typesafe Simple Snapshots", url("https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

//play snapshot 

resolvers +=  "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

// The Play plugin 

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" %% "sbt-plugin" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT")
```

in your build.sbt

```
//play snapshot 

resolvers +=  "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```